# Book where artistic people are thrown into a lake of acid; kids get teleported to a world where magic is real

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

In this world, anyone artistic is tossed into a lake of acid. But this wizard shows up and takes these kids to another world where magic exists, and they live in a mansion and use tubes to get around. The main character has a twin who lives in the other world and is not nice, but the character is very artistic, and there's a giant griffin statue who is alive and can fly.

Comment: Are you sure about the "lake of acid"? This seems like an obvious phrase to Google but doing so doesn't find anything related to your book.

Comment: It somehow reminds me of a question I saw last year, about a world where creativity (I think?) was forbidden. Or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is probably *[The Unwanteds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9917879-the-unwanteds)* by Lisa McMann. It was published in 2011, and is the first book in the *[Unwanteds Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/67764-unwanteds)*.

[image: Cover of "The Unwanted" showing a blocky, winged, lion-like creature flying towards the viewer, accompanied by tiny origami dragons. The pink one on the right with its mouth open is closest, followed the purple one on the left breathing fire and blue and green ones under the lion. What appear to be a boy and a girl are following behind, just outside a ruined gate. In the misty distance a massive mansion sits in front of towering rocks.]

According to [this summary](https://bookpage.com/interviews/8758-lisa-mcmann-childrens#.YDeSpdVxdEY) from bookpage.com, the main characters are Alex Stowe, a boy who is labelled Unwanted and condemned to death for being too creative, and his twin brother Aaron, who is labelled Wanted and offered a much brighter future:

> In The Unwanteds, children who are too creative or expressive are “purged” from their repressive community at age 13 and driven away to face the Eliminators and (they assume) certain death. In the Stowe family, young Aaron is selected for the prestigious “Wanted” group, while his twin brother Alex is labeled an “Unwanted” and led away in chains.

According to [this plot summary](https://www.pluggedin.com/book-reviews/unwanteds/) from pluggedin.com, Unwanted kids are condemned to death in "the Lake of Boiling Oil":

> Every year the land of Quill divides its 13-year-olds into three categories: Wanted, Necessary and Unwanted. This year, identical twins Aaron and Alex find themselves in different groups. Aaron is Wanted and destined for University, which will eventually let him become a leader in their land. Alex is Unwanted, and the Purge of the Unwanteds dooms him to death in **the Lake of Boiling Oil**. Although the brothers were not close, they each feel a surprising pull as they are separated by the Purge.

[The Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unwanteds_(novel)) mentions a "magical land of Artimè" and a "mage called Mr. Today", whom I suspect is the wizard you mentioned:

> When Alex and the other Unwanteds are dropped off at The Great Lake Of Boiling Oil, however, they are shocked to find themselves welcomed into **the magical land of Artimè**, created, hidden, and led by **a mage called Mr. Today**. While Alex and his new friends learn magic from art and creativity, Aaron displays loyalty and usefulness by creating the Favored Farm, an exclusive farm intended to provide the Wanteds of Quill with an abundance of healthy plants and animals. Through this action, he attracts the notice of High Priest Justine and rises to the prominent position of her assistant secretary. Alex soon begins to miss his brother Aaron which leads to big mistakes on Alex's part.

And [this review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/lisa-mcmann/unwanteds/) from kirkusreviews.com mentions "transporting tubes":

> On the day of Purge in totalitarian Quill, which is run by the High Priest Justine, 13-year-olds learn if they are deemed Wanted to attend the university, Necessary to tend the land or Unwanted and purged by execution. Without a good-bye from his Wanted identical brother Aaron, Alex Stowe and the other Unwanteds travel to the Death Farm. Instead of death, they meet the lush and magical world of Artimè, kept secret from Justine by mage Marcus Today. In a third-person narration characterized by even pacing and whimsical inventions, Alex and his peers learn that their creativity threatened Justine’s power. Surrounded by talking blackboards, **transporting tubes** and such fantastical creatures as an octagator (with the head of an alligator and body of an octopus) for instructors, the teens hone their drawing, music and acting skills while also wielding paintbrushes for invisibility spells and iambic pentameter to stun attackers during Magical Warrior Training, in preparation for battle against the Quillitary. As the youths explore fear, responsibility and free thinking, their spells may be used sooner than they think when Alex’s twin bond is tested and rivals vie for Aaron’s new position in Justine’s government.

The creature shown on the cover of the book is likely the griffin statue you mentioned.

You can read a preview of the book [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Unwanteds/1vaGtRYeFjAC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: thanks again from the bottom of my heart to everyone who helped me find the books which I cant remember thank you all